# parsing the date String with UTCOffset

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

The below link 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html
shows :

> "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"    2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-07:00

But when I try to do this in java/Eclipse:

```
SimpleDateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
try {
  Date d = df1.parse("2013-12-16T11:00:00.111-05:00");
  } catch (ParseException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

it says :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'X'

Please let me know, what I am missing

Answer (score 1):

The character `X` of the format pattern is only valid since Java 7! Unfortunately, it's nowhere written in the API docs...

So you have to run this piece of code with a Java 7 Runtime to make it work.